# Laravel how to do a subquery/custom relationship query for hasMany

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this problem where I am grouping by `account_name` and `ad_name`, but there are records that have the same `account_name` and `ad_name` while having different `ad_id`s(which I use for my relationship connection) - so I end up not connecting all my records.

```
 ...

        $selectList = [
            DB::raw("any_value(ad_id) as ad_id"),
            DB::raw("ad_name"),
            ...
        ];

        $query = Facebook::query()
            ->with(['cake:subid_1,price'])
            ->select($selectList)
            ->groupBy('ad_name', 'account_name');

      ...
```

This is how my relationship looks like:

```
    public function cake()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cake::class, 'subid_1', 'ad_id');
    }
```

and this is the underlying query it produces:

[image]

But what I think would actually solve my problem, would be something a query like this:

```
SELECT `price`,
       `subid_1`
FROM `cake_performance_data`
WHERE `cake_performance_data`.`subid_1` IN
    (SELECT ad_id
     FROM cake_performance_data
     WHERE ad_name IN ($arrayOfAdNames))
```

Can I somehow make this query using eloquent or actually any other solutions to achieve the same end goal would be good.

Comment: Share the schema for the tables and models, if created.

Comment: How do you expect to get $adnames?

Comment: Did my answer help or do you still have problems?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `$adNames` in the context, right now your code does not include it.

You can filter eager loading `with()` using and key value syntax. Secondly you can use a sub query in `WhereIn()` passing a closure.

```
->with(['cake' => function ($query) use ($adNames) {
    $query->whereIn('subid_1', function ($query) use ($adNames) {
        $query->select(['ad_id'])
            ->from((new Cake)->getTable())
            ->whereIn('ad_name ', $adNames);
    });
}]);
```